# PostgreSQL-9.5 array_to_json

Tags: postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.5

I am getting `T` while using `array_to_json` in `PostgreSQL-9.5` while its working fine with 9.2, Is there any configuration changes that I can make it work as 9.2 without changing the syntax of function

9.2:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(T)) from (select now()abc)t;
               array_to_json
-------------------------------------------
[{"abc":"2016-07-26 13:05:30.894412+00"}]
(1 row)
```

9.5:

```
select array_to_json(array_agg(T)) from (select now()abc)t;
                array_to_json
----------------------------------------------
[{"abc":"2016-07-26T13:04:52.352157+00:00"}]
(1 row)
```

Note: it works if we cast timestamp in text